# Paramiko: Execute a script on a remote server and actually see it running on remote desktop

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Executing a python script on a Windows VPS. I can see the output of the script printing on my local machine, but when I login to my VPS via remote desktop connection, I cannot see anything happening.

I am searching for a way to execute scripts remotely AND witness them running when I login via remote desktop. Is this possible?

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip, username=serverUser, password=serverPassword)
transport = ssh.get_transport()

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python test.py')
ssh_output = stdout.readlines()
print(ssh_output)
```

Comment: Can you do that using any commandline/GUI SSH client? I assume you cannot. So you won't be able to do it over SSH with Python/Paramiko either. So I believe you are asking a wrong question. You will most likely have to use another API, like the one suggested by @MichaelFriedel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ned,

I would try referring to this post here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/690852/use-powershell-to-start-a-gui-program-on-a-remote-machine

Executing the command remotely using PsExec with the -i arg seems to have worked for them. Documentation and info on PsExec can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec .